# Relation between two normal charts on a Riemannian manifolds?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-spaces, riemannian-geometry, inner-products

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold and $p\in M$ a point. Let $\{E_{i}\}$ be an orthonormal basis of $T_{p}M$ and let $E\colon \mathbb{R}^{n} \to T_{p}M$ be the isomorphism sending $(x_{1},\ldots,x_{n})\mapsto \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}E_{i}$. On a **normal neighborhood** $U$ of $p$ in $M$ (that is, the image under the exponential map $\exp_{p}$ of a star shaped open neighborhood $V$ of $0\in T_{p}M$) we can define a coordinate chart by $\varphi =E^{-1}\circ \exp_{p}^{-1}\colon U\to V\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$.

As is clear, the normal chart depends on choosing an orthonormal basis  $\{E_{i}\}$ of $T_pM.$ So let  $\{F_i\}$ be another orthonormal basis for $T_pM.$ Let  $F:(y_{1},\ldots,y_{n})\mapsto \sum_{i=1}^{n}y_{i}F_{i},$. Let $\psi:= F^{-1}\circ \exp_{p}^{-1}\colon U\to V\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$

**My question is:** **what can we say about $\psi\circ\phi^{-1}:V\to V?$** We note that: $\psi\circ\phi^{-1}=F^{-1}\circ E.$ I feel that it's the restriction to $V$ of an orthogonal transformation of $\mathbb{R}^{n},$ i.e. restriction of an orthogonal matrix, but  I'm having a difficult time proving it (if it's correct!). Clearly, the map  $\psi\circ\phi^{-1}$ is a bijective linear map, since both $E,F$ are so. But what I'm wondering here is: **does this preserve the inner product in $R^n?$**

**EDIT: I answered myself in the affirmative.**

Answer (score 0):

Choosing an orthonormal basis here is somewhat beside the point.  What you should do is use an $n$-dimensional inner product space $W$ (which is of course isometric to $\mathbb R^n$ once you choose coordinates).  Then consider a pair of isometries from $W$ to the tangent space, and see how the corresponding maps from $W$ to the manifold are related.  Choosing an orthonormal basis should be the last step, and not in $T_p M$ but rather in $W$.

Comment: Thank you, but I didn't understand your answer, apologies! First, I didn't understand what you concluded about $\psi\circ\phi^{-1}?$ Second, the manifold $M$ isn't important here, as the map  $\psi\circ\phi^{-1}$  doesn't have any exponential map in it, so we don't need to use tangent space in answering the question.  Third, did you mean isometries as vector spaces (not as inner product spaces)? Clearly, the map  $\psi\circ\phi^{-1}$ is a bijective linear map, since both $E,F$ are so. But what I'm wondering here is: does this preserve the inner product in $R^n?$

Comment: If you work with $W$ in place of $\mathbb R^n$, it becomes obvious that $\psi\circ\phi^{-1}$ is the original isometry of $W$ you started with.

Comment: Sorry but didn't understand again. What's not clear is if you meant isometry in the sense of a mere linear bijection, or one that preserves the inner product? Also, I don't see the point of replacing $R^n$ by $W,$ since $\psi\circ\phi^{-1}$ maps (an open subset of) $R^n$ to $R^n.$ If you're claiming that it's an inner product preserving isometry, i.e. an orthogonal matrix, I'd like to see a proof; else I'd like a counterexample.

Comment: @LearningMath, an isometry by definition preserves the inner product.  Also, what I suggest is replacing $\mathbb R^n$ by $W$, not vice versa.  Think of $\phi$ as a map from $W$ to the manifold (rather than a map from $\mathbb R^n$ to the manifold).

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, I meant I don't see the point of replacing $R^n$ but $W.$ Also, it's essentially a linear algebra question with no manifold structure necessary, as I explained above.

Comment: If you have an isometry $E: W\to T_p$, then $\exp \circ E$ is the corresponding normal chart.  Precomposing $E$ by a self-isometry of $W$ will give another normal chart.  They are obviously related by the self-isometry.

Comment: Sorry but that's not how normal chart is defined. Sure you can tweak it to mean something similar, but the definition is what I wrote above, borrowed from John Lee's standard textbook, or here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_coordinates. Moreover, I don't agree with you on "Choosing an orthonormal basis here is somewhat beside the point." (first line of your answer). Choosing an orthonormal basis plays the crucial role, as detailed in my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. **The answer is *yes*.** Below is the argument.

$E:\mathbb{R}^n\to T_p(M)$ is an **inner product space isometry** between $\mathbb{R}^n$ (canonical inner product) and $T_pM$ (inner product from the Riemannian metric), because $E$ preserves norms:

$$||E(x_1\dots x_n)||_{T_pM}^2=||\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_iE_i||_{T_pM}^2=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2= ||(x_1\dots x_n)||_{\mathbb{R}^n}^2$$

**Note that the above (especially, the second equality) is possible precisely because we chose an orthonormal basis $\{E_i\}$. Otherwise, it wouldn't be an isometry.**

Similarly, $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to T_p(M)$ is an inner product space isometry between $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $T_pM.$

So $\psi\circ\phi^{-1}= F^{-1}\circ E$ is a linear (inner product preserving) isometry from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to itself, i.e. restriction of an orthogonal matrix.